# Why netty doesn't use jemalloc directly but implement its own pool?

Tags: memory-management, netty, memory-pool, jemalloc

I find that netty implement a jemalloc-like memory pool for internel usage, I don't quite understand why, since the program could use jemalloc directly by using LD_PRELOAD or other mechanisms, is there any difference between these two approaches?

Comment: ¿Isn't netty a Java library?

Comment: I think the LD_PRELOAD works for all the program no matter it's C or Java, they would use malloc() under the hood internally.

Comment: Java programs don't use malloc on the first place. `LD_PRELOAD` does not mean much for them either.